# Values are not appending

Tags: ios, swift, arraylist, tableview

```
    import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource {
    

    var array = [Product]()
    
    
    @IBOutlet weak var tableview: UITableView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        self.tableview.delegate = self
        self.tableview.dataSource = self

        array.append(Product.init(image: UIImage(named: "a1")!))
        array.append(Product.init(image: UIImage(named: "a2")!))
        array.append(Product.init(image: UIImage(named: "a3")!))
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        array.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! TableViewCell
        
        cell.imageview.image = array[indexPath.row].image
        
        return cell
    }

}
```

This is viewController

```
import UIKit

class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var imageview: UIImageView!
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

}
```

This is tableviewcell

```
import UIKit

class Product
{
    var image: UIImage
    
    init(image: UIImage) {
        
        self.image = image
    }
}
```

This is class

I am creating a tableview using class like arraylist i have do this code when i run application it will be crash and getting hread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value this error it means that values are null so i want to fix how to fix why values are not appending

Comment: where your file storing in your storage folder ?

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tableview id missing now added working fine

Answer (score 0):

using **storage_path()**

```
<img src="{{storage_path().'app/public/images/'.$category->thumbnail}}" width="100" height="100" />
```

and if you linked storage path with **public** path like [Link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/filesystem)

```
php artisan storage:link

<img src="{{asset('storage/images/'.$category->thumbnail)}}" width="100" height="100" />
```